# SQL query - how to calculate group total for every item from groups of items

Tags: sql

I'm trying to calculate total revenue for every product and total revenue from orders with every product from my data set.

Sample date:

| item | order id | revenue |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | 1 | 10 |
| b | 1 | 15 |
| c | 1 | 50 |
| a | 2 | 10 |
| b | 2 | 15 |

Expected result:

| item | item total | orders with item total |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | 20 | 100 |
| b | 30 | 100 |
| c | 50 | 75 |

I'm using `group by` statement to calculate total revenue by product

```
select sum(revenue) from dataset group by item
```

but I can't calculate total from orders with products with subquery like this (I have total or all orders in column order_total):

```
select sum(revenue) 
     , (select sum(revenue) from dataset
        where order_id in (select distinct order_id from
                           dataset where item=item)) as order_total
from dataset 
group by item
```

Is this correct: `dataset where item=item`?

Comment: Please tag the appropriate database engine that you're using.

Comment: your data has issues. if `a item total` is 20 (10+10),  then `b item total` should be 30 (15+15). order with item total makes no sense either 100 is the total sum of all sales.

Comment: @DannySlor it appears that they are trying to sum 2 different things. The total of the item sold, AND the total sales orders that those items are sold in. You are correct on your b total. It should be 30. But then they are summing the entire cost of the order that that item is in for some reason. I do not see doing this with a single query, you would probably need a sub query to complete this, because you are summing on multiple items and multiple groupings. One grouping by sales order that include that item, one grouping by item.

Comment: @RobertShannon The sum by order would be 75 and 25. I can do it but it will have to be shown with duplicates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you @shawnt00, but I think subquery will be better for me in this case.

Query works with dataset aliases (ds1 and ds2):

```
select ds1.item, sum(revenue) as item_total
     , (select sum(revenue) from dataset
        where orderid in (select distinct orderid from
                           dataset as ds2 
                           where ds1.item=ds2.item)) as orders_with_item_total
from dataset as ds1
group by ds1.item
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=1bd20d6fb39029ce71cbeda87062f7e4

Answer (score 1):

My first thought was along these lines except I knew that SQL Server wouldn't like it because of the way it sums. It does work on Postgres though (with a lateral join. See link below):

```
select *
from
    (select distinct item from dataset) t1 cross apply
    (
    select
        sum(case when t2.item = t1.item then revenue end) as item_revenue,
        sum(revenue) as total_revenue
    from dataset t2
    group by order_id
    -- use a count if revenue > 0 isn't a reliable check
    having sum(case when t2.item = t1.item then revenue end) > 0
    ) agg;
```

The cleaner (and portable) answer would seem to be:

```
select t1.item,
    sum(case when t1.item = t2.item then t2.revenue end) as item_revenue,
    sum(t2.revenue) as total_revenue
from dataset t1 inner join dataset t2 on t2.orderid = t1.orderid
group by t1.item;
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=321a085216236465cc9b76a7f458c6f5